# Javascript code won't open XML file and put into table

Tags: javascript, xml, file

I know this may be a silly question but for this application I cannot figure out why the code wont open the XML file and put it in the table. What is the problem?

```
<script type ="text/javascript">



function displayData() {

var xmlEl =docObj.getElementsByTagName("books");
var table = document.createElement("table");

table.border = "1";
var tbody = document.createElement("tbody");

//Append body to table
table.appendChild(tbody);
var row = document.createElement("tr");

for(colHead=0; colHead < xmlEl[0].childNodes.length; colHead++){
if(xmlEl[0].childNodes[colHead].nodeType !== 1){
continue;
}
var tableHead = document.createElement("th");
var colName = document.createTextNode(xmlEL[0].childNodes[colHead].nodeName);
tableHead.appendChild(colName);
row.appendChild(tableHead);
}

//Append the row to the body
tbody.appendChild(row);

// Create table row
for(i=0; i < xmlEl.length; i++){
    row = document.createElement("tr");
    // Create the row/td elements
    for(j=0; j <xmlEl[i].childNodes.length; j++){
        //Skip it if the type is not 1
        if(xmlEl[i].childNodes[j].nodeType !== 1){
        continue;
    }

//Insert the actual text/data from the XML document
var td =document.createElement("td");
var xmlData =
    document.createTextNode(xmlEl[i].childNodes[j].firstChild.nodeValue);
    td.appendChild(xmlData);
    row.appendChild(td);
}
tbody.appendChild(row);
}

document.getElementById("xmldata").appendChild(table);

}

function getXML() {
    if(typeof document.implementation.createDocument !== "undefined"){
    docObj = document.implementation.createDocument("","", null);
    docObj.onload = displayData;

}
else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    docObj = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
    docObj.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if(docObj.readyState === 4) displayData()
    };
    }
    docObj.load("books.xml");
}

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<books>
<book>
    <title>MySQL Bible</title>
    <author>Steve Sueshring</author>
    <isbn>978764549328</isbn>
    <publisher>Wiley Publishing, Inc.</publisher>
</book>
<book>
    <title>Javascript Step By Step</title>
    <author>Steve Sueshring</author>
    <isbn>978735624498</isbn>
    <publisher>Microsoft Press</publisher>
</book>
</books>
```

Comment: What happens or doesn't happen? What errors do you get?

Comment: I get a blank page and an error that cant find my xmlEl variable value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like your running the script on the client browser, in that case you do not have access to the file system, most likely you are getting "Access Denied" exception

Comment: How do I fix it? I know very little about AJAX at the moment.

Comment: Thanks, but I copied this example from a book I'd really like to know why it is wrong.

Comment: Added an onload event for IE and Firefox.